# Why does my baked texture come out greyscale with no image texture or color?

Tags: texture-baking, baking

Alright so I'm currently attempting to bake and export textures for a model that I want to send over to Unreal Engine 5. I've tried baking it to the character model but the model is way too complex, I've tried decreasing vertices etc. but it just ends up looking rubbish. I'll attach a blend file, if you could take a look and attempt to sort things that'd be amazing. If you're able to, and would like to I would love to attach the model as well, if you're able to sort that out that'd be absolutely amazing. I'm at an intermediate level with blender so i apologise if this is really obvious

Desired texture:

[image: Desired texture]

Baked diffuse:

[image]

Blender File:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove the "Mix Shader" and "Shader to RGB" nodes and use a "Mix Color" one instead, Shader to RGB it meant for EEVEE renderer I don't think it is useful with baking in Cycles.

[image]

[image]